# GitHub workflow after pull request review and commits

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have forked a public repo on GitHub, created a branch, pushed the branch/changes to the forked repo and then created a pull request to the original repo.

Now the owner of the repo reviewed my code and requested some changes. Now what I want to do:

- Update the code taking the review comments into account
- Also I am seeing, that in the meantime, my branch is "1 commit ahead, 4 commits behind exampleRepo:main", what I also now want to take into account

My question: What is the workflow now for me to take everything into account?

From my point of view I see two options, but I am not sure which one is the right one without breaking something.

Option 1:

1. Update the code based on review comments in same branch
2. Commit changes in same branch as before
3. Push changes to my forked repo
4. Create pull request with last commit

Or Option 2:

1. First run "git pull" locally to get all recent changes (because my forked repo is "4 commits behind" as stated above)
2. Update the code based on review comments in same branch
3. Commit changes in same branch as before
4. Push changes to my forked repo
5. Create pull request with last commit

Or do you see another option and workflow I should use for that?

Answer (score 0):

The message from git tells that someone else pushed to main since the time you made the PR.

You could still keep your PR if the files you changed don't conflict with main, but it might be cleaner to do a git rebase of your branch on top of main.

The rebase will rewrite the history of your branch and you will have to git push --force **SO** make sure nobody else is working on that branch.

The PR from github will then *adjust* automatically